# how to set classpath with javac compiler at runtime?

Tags: java

Suppose I need  Servlet file to be compiled runtime using another servlet
and I want set class path of servlet-api.jar and how to do that I tried following way.....

```
 String servletjar=sc.getRealPath("WEB-INF\\lib/servlet-api.jar; ");
 cmdArray[0] = "javac -cp "+servletjar;
 cmdArray[1] = sc.getRealPath("WEB-INF\\classes\\src\\Login.java");
 Process process1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArray,null);
```

Comment: that sounds wrong on so many levels.

Comment: welcome to SO, please read the documentations about how to ask a good question and edit your post.

Comment: If you understand tell me only ans....

Comment: Maybe you should use the [compiler API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/package-summary.html)?

Comment: What wrong with your current code? It throw exception or do not work correctly in some way?

Comment: You're misusing `Runtime.exec()` (either use a string or an array with one token per cell), and you shouldn't be using it in the first place.

Comment: in case simple file                                                                          
       cmdArray[0] = "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/javac.exe";                         
       cmdArray[1] = sc.getRealPath("WEB-INF\\classes\\src\\Login.java");             Process process1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArray,null);  compiling  but using servlet code and its adding jar path not compiling

Answer (score 1):

So many problems here, so little time.

1. `servlet-api.jar` will be provided by the container, not on the path you mentioned.
2. The `src` directory won't be there at runtime at all, let alone in a directory called `WEB-INF\\classes\\src`.
3. If you have a fixed file called `Login.java` it is impossible to see why you would need to compile it at runtime at all.
4. The `cmdArray` is intended to hold one argument per element. Not three in one element and one in another.

Comment: for developing online compiler project

Comment: For developing an online compiler project where everything you compile is in a file called `src/Login.java`? Really? And what about the other three issues I mentioned?